# How can I run an Apache Spark remote from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark

I have a Spark cluster setup with one master and 3 workers.
I Use vagrant and Docker to start a cluster.

I'm trying to submit a Spark work from my local eclipse which would connect to the master, and allow me to execute it. So, here is the Spark Conf :

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("spark://scale1.docker:7077");
```

When I run my application from eclipse on Master's UI, I can see one running application. All the workers are ALIVE, have 4 / 4 cores used, and have allocated 512 MB to the application.

The eclipse console will just print the same warning:

```
15/03/04 15:39:27 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_1_piece0
15/03/04 15:39:27 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:838
15/03/04 15:39:27 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MappedRDD[2] at mapToPair at CountLines.java:35)
15/03/04 15:39:27 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
15/03/04 15:39:42 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
15/03/04 15:39:57 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150304143926-0001/1 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150304143926-0001/1 removed: Command exited with code 1
15/03/04 15:40:04 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 1
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150304143926-0001/2 on worker-20150304140319-scale3.docker-55425 (scale3.docker:55425) with 4 cores
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150304143926-0001/2 on hostPort scale3.docker:55425 with 4 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150304143926-0001/2 is now RUNNING
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150304143926-0001/2 is now LOADING
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150304143926-0001/0 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150304143926-0001/0 removed: Command exited with code 1
15/03/04 15:40:04 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150304143926-0001/3 on worker-20150304140317-scale2.docker-60646 (scale2.docker:60646) with 4 cores
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150304143926-0001/3 on hostPort scale2.docker:60646 with 4 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150304143926-0001/3 is now RUNNING
15/03/04 15:40:04 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150304143926-0001/3 is now LOADING
```

Reading Spark Documentation of Spark I have find this:

> Because the driver schedules tasks on the cluster, it should be run
>   close to the worker nodes, preferably on the same local area network.
>   If you’d like to send requests to the cluster remotely, it’s better to
>   open an RPC to the driver and have it submit operations from nearby
>   than to run a driver far away from the worker nodes.

I think the problem is due to the driver that runs locally on my machine.

I am using Spark 1.2.0.

Is it possible to run application in eclipse and submit it to remote cluster using local driver? If so, what can I do?

Comment: I think the problem is your Vagrant/Docker networking settings. When you start the Driver app it connects to the Master which select Slaves which connect back to the Driver app to report results. So your Spark Master/Slaves must be able to talk to the Driver app. Check you can ping your host from your containers. You can tune the Driver app port using `spark.driver.port` setting

Answer (score 0):

remote dubugging is quite possible and it works fine with below option executed on edge node.

--driver-java-options -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005

[Debugging Spark Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090745/debugging-spark-applications)
you need not to speicify the master or anything. here is the sample command.

spark-submit --master yarn-client --class org.hkt.spark.jstest.javascalawordcount.JavaWordCount --driver-java-options -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 javascalawordcount-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar